# Multiple arrays not outputting headers

Tags: powershell

I have several sets of results from running `Compare-Object` on files.  I want to output these to the console.  When I try to write them to the console I get one set of headers, and it visually puts everything from all successive sets in the same table.

Is there a way to modify my script so that it outputs headers for each separate result set?

Currently I am doing something like this:

```powershell
ForEach ($result in $results) {
  $result
}
```

---

In the above, `$results` is an array of the results from `Compare-Object`.  That means that each `$result` is itself an array.  I want the output of each `$result` to have its own set of headers.

Comment: So you want each record to have its own header, or one set of headers that covers all possible recordsets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEach ($result in $results) { $result | format-table }

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx